# Robot Framework: non-critical tag is not working

Tags: robotframework

Setting non-critical tag to the test is not working and still the test remain as critical (see attached screen shot).
Is there some workaround?

[image]

Comment: I noticed that all failures are passed along to the xUnit.XML file, which has no concept of non-critical. At least in my version of Bamboo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell robot which tags are critical and which are not. When you run your tests you need to include the command line argument `--noncritical non-critical`

For example:

```
$ pybot --noncritical non-critical mysuite.robot
```